# Trying to use external reference in Postman with tv4

Tags: validation, reference, external, postman, tv4

I'm trying to use an external reference in Postman and validating that with tv4.
This is my code:

```
  var schema = tv4.getSchema('https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v1/');
  console.log(tv4.validate(responseBody, schema);
```

and after testing I get

> 'TypeError Cannot read property '$ref' of undefined'

.

Does that mean my schema is not valid somehow?

Comment: I get the same error. I know that I am able to get that my schema via an HTTP Get request. Also, when I put it in the JSON.Schema validator, that says it's OK. So not sure how it's failing.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late, but this could help others

`tv4.getSchema(name)` is used to retrieve an already loaded schema. `tv4.addSchema(name, schema)` is used to append a new schema of *name* with *schema* value

#### So, what should you do?

Reading [this article](http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/07/28/api-testing-tips-from-a-postman-professional/) I understood that you can't make two requests in a test using Postman. Instead you should store its value in a environment or global variable and don't use tv4's functions as those (I guess) were meant to be used in environments where you can actually download a schema using `http` module.

Finally, your example should look as this

```
var schema = JSON.parse(postman.getEnvironmentVariable('myEnvVarName'));
let valid = tv4.validate(pm.response.json(), schema, false, true);
```